# Nginx on OSX: "server" directive is not allowed here

Tags: macos, nginx

I'm trying to serve a Node application through Nginx on my Mac, and I've run into a problem.

On Ubuntu, I always change the config file to this

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

but when I do the same on my Mac, I get this error when I'm running the server:

> nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in
>   /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

Any suggestions on why this is happening would be appreciated.

Comment: What file is that you've edited, and how is it included into your `nginx.conf` file?

Comment: Is this the complete nginx.conf? On my nginx.conf it is prepended with a http-block.

Comment: @DaveWood I've configured the /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

Comment: @kometen Yes this is the complete conf file, it's what I use on my ubuntu servers.

Comment: @martin OK. Then I'll undelete my answer. I was a bit unshure. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to nginx's [page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#conf_structure) http is the outer block. So it should work be adding a http block before the server block.

Answer (score 0):

By doing that i get `host not found in "$PORT" of the "listen" directive`

```
http {
    server {
    listen $PORT;
    server_name test-rpc.test.com;
    location / {
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass http://test-rpc;
    }
    }

    upstream test-rpc {
        server localhost:2000 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
        server localhost:2001 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
    }
}
```